# How to shade multiple areas python

Tags: python, region

Suppose we have three functions of `p`:

- f1(p)
- f2(p)
- f3(p)

that depend on the same parameter `p`

Let `R(p)` be the region of the plane such that:

```
x <= f1(p)   
y <= f2(p)
x + y <= f3(p)
```

Then we define the region `R` such that `R` is the union of the `R(p)` on a certain interval of `p` (finite).

How can I shade the region `R` and print it?

That is, shade the regions `R(p)` for each value of `p` on the same graph).

Comment: More context is needed for a good answer. Are functions `f1(p), f2(p), f3(p)` continuous in the given interval for `p`? How do you know the "viewport" of the graph (max & min x and y values shown)? Do you need the whole plane or is the first quadrant sufficient? Do you need every point in `R` colored or can the region have an approximate shading (such as lines from upper left to lower right)? Is the performance acceptable if sub-regions for each `p` are shaded over each other or do you need to avoid shading points multiple times? What graphing/graphics modules do you know?

Comment: Yes, the functions fi(p) are continuous. The first quadrant is sufficient, we can assume that f1(p) f2(p) are < 2. It is not a problem if we shade points multiple times, I don't know any graphics module because i'm a beginner, I just need this graph to visualize something. Thank you